# Is safe to delete .cache folder in node_modules?

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install

My project size reached 1.2GB, and it was caused by the **.cache** folder inside the **npm module**. Is it safe if I delete that folder?

[image]

Comment: There's a command for it, `npm cache clean`: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/cache.html

Comment: thanks, I'll read it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

generally, it is safe to delete the `node_modules` folder, as it can be regenerated by the package manager.
Package versions may change during reinstall (unless you have a `*.lock` file)

Comment: I trashed my `node_modules` folder and then did `npm i` and that worked for me. The `node_modules/.cache` file was 7GB and using my computers disc space slowing my computer down. I don't know why the `.cache` needs to take up that much space but I'm glad to free up some space on my computer. thanks!

Comment: it mainly contains sideffect files like webpack build objects, and packages have no incentive to remove files from this folder. It may make sense to remove the folder once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

if it is safe to delete it, and you can recreate it when you compile or when you generate the build